# Why does the minor pentatonic scale sounds "oriental" to me?

Tags: scales

I've been training my minor pentatonic scale on guitar for a while (mostly playing it in A with the *first position*) and it always sounded somewhat oriental to me, in the sense of the musical airs you'd find in music to set the plot in Orient, musical clichés. I am not sure to be really clear in trying to share this impression, but I, then, read that in Orient they used to split the octave in 5 tones, and not 7 as we did in Europe, would it be because the pentatonic as only five notes (by definition) that my sub

Comment: Weird, the Major pentatonic sounds more foreign to me.

Comment: Does 'oriental' necessarily mean 'foreign'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a strong east oriental feel to pentatonic music, as the structure of the scales used fits this mode well.

This is best symbolised by the 'Oriental Riff' http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_riff

So any music you play utilising a pentatonic scale could sound very Oriental.

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia page. Just a little thing that'll help trusting a bit more my ears ;)